# Use PHP to enter value from form in to multiple tables in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Im doing a registration form and I have to enter the information in to 3 tables in mysql. I have tried a few things but cant seem to get it right. This is what I have so far. My registration form looks as follows:

```
function fix($str){
    $str = trim($str);
    $str = stripslashes($str);
    return $str;            
}
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $first = fix($_POST['firstName']);
    $last = fix($_POST['lastName']);
    $email = fix($_POST['email']);
    $userName = fix($_POST['userName']);
    $passWord = fix($_POST['passWord']);
    $reTyped = fix($_POST['confPassword']);
    $secA = $_POST['secA'];
    $secQ = $_POST['secQ'];

    require_once('user_registration.php');

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE, Head, Body & Nav here>
<div class="account-container register">
<div class="content clearfix">
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <h1>New User Registration</h1>          
        <div class="login-fields">

            <div class="field">
                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text"  id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" class="login" />

            </div> <!-- /field -->
            <div class="field">
                <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>    
                <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="login" />
            </div> <!-- /field -->

            <div class="field">
                <label for="userName">User Name:</label>
                <input  type="text" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="User Name" class="login" />
            </div><!-- /field -->

            <div class="field">
                <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                <input  type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="login" />
            </div> <!-- /field -->

            <div class="field">
                <label for="passWord">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="passWord" name="passWord" placeholder="Password" class="login" />
                </div> <!-- /field -->

            <div class="field">
                <label for="confPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="confPassword" name="confPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="login" />
            </div><!--field-->

        <div class="field">
                <label for="secQ">Security Question</label>
                <select name="secQ" id="secQuestion" placeholder="Security" class="dropdown">
                    <option value="No Selection"
                    <?php if(!$_POST || $_POST['secQ'] == 'No Selection')
                    { echo 'selected'; }?>>--Select A Security Question--</option>
                    <option value="0"
                    <?php if(!$_POST || $_POST['secQ'] == '0')
                    { echo 'selected'; }?>>What is your mothers maiden name</option>
                    <option value="1"
                    <?php if(!$_POST || $_POST['secQ'] == '1')
                    { echo 'selected'; }?>>In what city were you born</option>
                    <option value="2"
                    <?php if(!$_POST || $_POST['secQ'] == '2')
                    { echo 'selected'; }?>>What is your favorite color</option>
                    <option value="3"
                    <?php if(!$_POST || $_POST['secQ'] == '3')
                    { echo 'selected'; }?>>What year did you graduate HighSchool</option>
                    <option value="4"
                    <?php if(!$_POST || $_POST['secQ'] == '4')
                    { echo 'selected'; }?>>What is the name of your first boy/girl friend</option>
                    <option value="5"
                    <?php if(!$_POST || $_POST['secQ'] == '5')
                    { echo 'selected'; }?>>What was the name of your first pet</option>
                    <option value="6"
                    <?php if(!$_POST || $_POST['secQ'] == '6')
                    { echo 'selected'; }?>>What street did you grow up on</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="secA">Security Answer</label>
                <input type="text" id="secA" name="secA" placeholder="Answer" class="login" />
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /login-fields -->
        <div class="login-actions">
            <span class="login-checkbox">
                <input id="Field" name="terms" type="checkbox" class="field login-checkbox" value="First Choice" tabindex="4" />
                <label class="choice" for="Field">Agree with the Terms & Conditions.</label>
            </span>         
            <input type="submit" id="register" name="submit" class="button btn btn-primary btn-large" value="Register" />
        </div> <!-- .actions -->
    </form>
</div> <!-- /content -->
```

Then the PHP page I have attached to the form as noted in the first "if" statement is the following - user_registration.php:

```
<?php

require_once('includes/checkPassword.php');
$usernameMinChars = 6;
$errors = array();

if (strlen($userName) < $usernameMinChars) 
{
    $errors[] = "Username must be at least $usernameMinChars characters.";
}

if (preg_match('/\s/', $userName)) 
{
    $errors[] = 'Username should not contain spaces.';
}

$checkPwd = new CheckPassword($passWord);
$checkPwd->requireMixedCase();

$passwordOK = $checkPwd->check();
if (!$passwordOK) {
$errors[] = array_merge($errors, $checkPwd->getErrors());
}
if ($passWord != $reTyped) {
$errors[] = "Your passwords don't match.";
}
if (!$errors) {
//include connection file
require('includes/usrConnect.php');
$conn = dbConnect('write');
//create salt using current timestamp
$salt = SALT .time();
//encrypt pwd with salt
$hashword = sha1($passWord . $salt);

//prepare sql statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO User (User_Name) VALUES('$userName')";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO User_Parameter (User_Identity, User_Password, User_Salt) VALUES('$User_Identity', '$hashword', '$salt')";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO User_Profile (User_Identity, Profile_FirstName, Profile_LastName, Profile_Email, Profile_Question, Profile_Answer) 
        VALUES('$User_Identity', '$first', '$last', '$email', '$secQ', '$secA')";

if($stmt = $conn->query($sql))
{
    $User_Identity = $stmt->insert_id;
    do{
        if($result = $conn->affected_rows())
        {
            while ($result > 0)
            {
                $success = 'User successfully created '.$User_Identity;
                header('Location: login.php');
            }
        } $result->free();
    }while($conn->next_result());
}
elseif($stmt->errno == 1062)
{
    $errors[] = "$userName already exists, Please select another username.";
}else{
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, there was a problem processing your request.';
}

}
?>
```

The problem is that I have 3 tables to insert the information in to. User(for the user_name), User_Parameter(for the password & salt), & User_Profile(for the name, email, & security question / answer).
I just cant figure out how to do the queries correctly. I have tried it this way and I have also tried naming each query something different and can't get it nested correctly in order to correctly get the User_Identity from the first insert in order to input the information in the other queries. Can anyone help?

Comment: Uff, why people in year 2014 are still writing code that looks like from year 2000? Anyway, the solution for your problem is to run each query separately. Table `user` with only `username` column is completely redundant as the `user_name` column could be inside the `user_profile` table (or columns from `user_profile` should be moved to `user` and table `user_profile` removed). And merged altogether with the table `user_identity` - then you have only one table to insert to. I cannot answer your question properly as you have most probably a really wrong database model.

Comment: Im new ro programming @shadyyx why is it that trolls like you with nothing constructive to say still come to these fourums?

Comment: Because trolls like you with non-constructive questions still comes here to ask newbie questions and steal our time... Anyway, my comment is as constructive as it could be - your database model is incorrect and I suggested to improve it - to merge those three tables into just one. If I had nothing constructive to say I wouldn't have the rep I have right now. You made my day :-D

Answer (score 0):

I think you must execute these 3 queries separately, it actually will work.

```
$conn->query("INSERT INTO User (User_Name) VALUES('$userName')");
$conn->query("INSERT INTO User_Parameter (User_Identity, User_Password, User_Salt) VALUES('$User_Identity', '$hashword', '$salt')");
$stmt = $conn->query("INSERT INTO User_Profile (User_Identity, Profile_FirstName, Profile_LastName, Profile_Email, Profile_Question, Profile_Answer) VALUES('$User_Identity', '$first', '$last', '$email', '$secQ', '$secA')");
if ($stmt) {
    // then your code goes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think just complete this three tables into one.

and using one insert query